# Dynamically added remove button not working on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my simple code to get users search history in a certain div. This return search history inside a div and these search data save on localstorage. I have added a close btn, when users click on this close btn, this specific search data should remove from search history as well as from localstorage. But why this close btn not working ?

Another fact is after adding this close btn, it even not working click select from search history. Why this is happening ?

Heres my complete code:

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
  var $searchInput = $('#searchInput');
  var $searchBtn = $('#searchBtn');
  var $searchSuggestions = $('#searchSuggestions');
  var searchHistory = [];

  $searchInput.on('input', function() {
    var searchTerm = $searchInput.val().toLowerCase();
    var suggestions = getSuggestions(searchTerm);
    displaySuggestions(suggestions);
  });

  $searchInput.on('focus', function() {
    var searchTerm = $searchInput.val().toLowerCase();
    var suggestions = getSuggestions(searchTerm);
    displaySuggestions(suggestions);
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#searchInput, #searchSuggestions').length) {
      $searchSuggestions.hide();
    }
  });

  function getSuggestions(searchTerm) {
    var storedSearchHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchHistory'));
    if (storedSearchHistory !== null) {
      searchHistory = storedSearchHistory;
    }
    var filteredSearchHistory = searchHistory.filter(function(item) {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1;
    });
    return filteredSearchHistory;
  }

function displaySuggestions(suggestions) {
  $searchSuggestions.empty();
  if (suggestions.length > 0) {
    $searchSuggestions.show();
    for (var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
      var suggestion = $('<div class="suggestion">' + suggestions[i] + '</div>');
      var removeButton = $('<button class="remove-btn">X</button>');
      suggestion.append(removeButton);
      $searchSuggestions.append(suggestion);
    }
  } else {
    $searchSuggestions.hide();
  }
}

  $(document).on('click', '.suggestion', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('removeBtn')) {
      var suggestion = $(event.target).prev().text();
      var suggestionIndex = searchHistory.indexOf(suggestion);
      if (suggestionIndex !== -1) {
        searchHistory.splice(suggestionIndex, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('searchHistory', JSON.stringify(searchHistory));
        displaySuggestions(getSuggestions($searchInput.val().toLowerCase()));
      }
    } else {
      var suggestion = $(this).text();
      $searchInput.val(suggestion);
      $searchSuggestions.hide();
    }
  });

  $searchBtn.on('click', function() {
    var searchTerm = $searchInput.val();
    if (searchTerm.trim() !== '') {
      searchHistory.push(searchTerm);
      localStorage.setItem('searchHistory', JSON.stringify(searchHistory));
      displaySuggestions([]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  #searchInput {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 250px;
    }

    #searchBtn {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #searchBtn:hover {
      background-color: #3E8E41;
    }

    #searchSuggestions {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: none;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 6px;
    }

    .suggestion {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
      background: #f3f3f3;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .suggestion:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .remove-btn{
    border: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

```html
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your search term here...">
        <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
        <div id="searchSuggestions"></div>
```

Comment: Anybody Know the Answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to fix the button class identifier:

```
if ($(event.target).hasClass('remove-btn')) {
```

2. Fix string selector not to include child text, now it's including `x` from the button, so that `indexOf` always fails:

```
var suggestion = $(event.target).parent().contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3; }).text();
```

**EDIT**

Any click will hide the list, which is why it's being hidden on removal.
To make the list remain open on removal, prevent it from being hidden on click here, for example hide it only in case the `remove-btn` is not clicked:

```
if (!$(event.target).closest('#searchInput, #searchSuggestions').length) {
  if(!$(event.target).hasClass('remove-btn')) $searchSuggestions.hide();
}
```

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $searchInput = $('#searchInput');
  var $searchBtn = $('#searchBtn');
  var $searchSuggestions = $('#searchSuggestions');
  var searchHistory = [];

  $searchInput.on('input', function() {
    var searchTerm = $searchInput.val().toLowerCase();
    var suggestions = getSuggestions(searchTerm);
    displaySuggestions(suggestions);
  });

  $searchInput.on('focus', function() {
    var searchTerm = $searchInput.val().toLowerCase();
    var suggestions = getSuggestions(searchTerm);
    displaySuggestions(suggestions);
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('#searchInput, #searchSuggestions').length) {
      $searchSuggestions.hide();
    }
  });

  function getSuggestions(searchTerm) {
    var storedSearchHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchHistory'));
    if (storedSearchHistory !== null) {
      searchHistory = storedSearchHistory;
    }
    var filteredSearchHistory = searchHistory.filter(function(item) {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1;
    });
    return filteredSearchHistory;
  }

function displaySuggestions(suggestions) {
  $searchSuggestions.empty();
  if (suggestions.length > 0) {
    $searchSuggestions.show();
    for (var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
      var suggestion = $('<div class="suggestion">' + suggestions[i] + '</div>');
      var removeButton = $('<button class="remove-btn">X</button>');
      suggestion.append(removeButton);
      $searchSuggestions.append(suggestion);
    }
  } else {
    $searchSuggestions.hide();
  }
}

  $(document).on('click', '.suggestion', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('remove-btn')) {
          var suggestion = $(event.target).parent().contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3; }).text();
          var suggestionIndex = searchHistory.indexOf(suggestion);
      if (suggestionIndex !== -1) {
        searchHistory.splice(suggestionIndex, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('searchHistory', JSON.stringify(searchHistory));
        displaySuggestions(getSuggestions($searchInput.val().toLowerCase()));
      }
    } else {
      var suggestion = $(this).contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3; }).text();
      $searchInput.val(suggestion);
      $searchSuggestions.hide();
    }
  });

  $searchBtn.on('click', function() {
    var searchTerm = $searchInput.val();
    if (searchTerm.trim() !== '') {
      searchHistory.push(searchTerm);
      localStorage.setItem('searchHistory', JSON.stringify(searchHistory));
      displaySuggestions([]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#searchInput {
      padding: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 250px;
    }

    #searchBtn {
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #searchBtn:hover {
      background-color: #3E8E41;
    }

    #searchSuggestions {
      position: absolute;
      width: 250px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: none;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 6px;
    }

    .suggestion {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
      background: #f3f3f3;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .suggestion:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    .remove-btn{
    border: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <input type="text" id="searchInput" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your search term here...">
        <button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
        <div id="searchSuggestions"></div>
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks @traynor. But it should remove just the sugession. It removes complete div at a time. Though it's enough for me. But it would be good for me if it just remove the item name. Not complete div.

Comment: well, it's hidden because of the part that hides it upon any click. So, that's the part that needs to be modified. Try the updated code, it should remain open on removal

Comment: Actually, the div with the suggestions needs to be re-rendered, to pick up the fresh list from local storage, so it's being re-rendered every time, instead of open..

Comment: I got my complete solution.

Comment: try the updated code, it should omit child nodes' text, the same as the upper part

Comment: ..and it could be also declared above the if blocks to respect DRY principle, as well as the whole code could use some refactoring..

Comment: Amazing @traynor. Now everything is OK as I wanted